# Непроизносимые согласные в корне

Tags: орфография

В известном правиле о непроизносимых согласных в корнях слов говорится, что для правильного написания нужно подобрать проверочное слово: устный - уста, агентство -агент и т.д. Обычно слово "чувство" предлагается запомнить. Но может быть, его можно как-то объяснить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что в ***словаре Фасмера*** есть ответ на этот вопрос.
Чувство.
 Ближайшая этимология: Чувствовать, русск.-цслав. Чувьство A‡sqhsij, ст.-слав. чоувьствиЉ (Еuсh. Sin.), диал. У-Чувать "услышать, заметить", цслав. По-Чувати, болг. Чувам "слышу", сербохорв. чувати, чу? ва? м "охранять, стеречь", словен. ‰uґvati "бодрствовать, стеречь", далее связано с Чую, Чуть, Чуять. 
 Очевидно, что в славянских языках после [В] в словах с этим корнем часто употреблялся гласный звук. Если вы хотите подобрать проверочное слово к "чувствовать", используйте любое из приведённых у Фасмера. Думаю, что это будет интересно.

Comment: Катя, спасибо за убеждающий и аргументированный ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Объяснение, возможно, будет найдено при обращении к этимологии слова.

Соврем. форма слова **ЧУВСТВО** возникла из др.-рус. *чувьство* «чувствование, способность чувствовать», «сознание, понимание» вследствие утраты слаб. редуцир. ь и видоизменения знач. Др.-рус. (и ст.-сл.) *чувьство* восходит к праслав. *čuvьstvo , образование которого объясняется по-разному. Одни считают, что оно произведено с пом. суф. отвлеч. имен -ьstv-o > -ств-о (как* коварство*) от утрач.* čuvъ > чувъ «чувство», в свою очередь образованного с суф. -v-ъ (как *сев*) от глаг. *čuti > чути «слышать, чувствовать». Ср. др.-рус. и ст.-cл.* чувь *«существо, одаренное силой чувствования»; схв.* чув *«внимание». От* čuvъ «чувство, ощущение» образован с суф. -a-ti глаг. *čuvati, давший др.-рус. чувати «слыхать», сохранившийся в укр. яз. чувати «слыхать» и рус. диал. чувать «ощущать, чувствовать».

Другие полагают, что праслав. *čuvьstvo образовано непосредственно от глаг.* čuti, давшего др.-рус. *чути* «чувствовать, ощущать», «слышать», «знать, сознавать», от которого происходит укр. *чути* «слышать», «чуять», «чувствовать». При этом между корнем *ču и суф. -ьstv-o вставлен звук -V- для устранения зияния.

Таким образом, корневая согласная **В** в современном слове **чуВство** объясняется этимологически.

Comment: >Одни считают,  

А другие?

Comment: Спасибо, Ольга, это очень интересно. В доступных мне справочниках и словарях ничего не нашел. Если не трудно, поделитесь, пожалуйста, ссылками на этимологические словари.

Comment: Я не вижу принципиально противоречия между "одними" и "другими".  
В конце концов все сводится к морфу čuti.

Вот насчет "устранения зияния" - это сильно. В в подобных случаях никогда не вставляеется после у, только перед. Пред ерем, как и всеми гласными переднего ряда должен быь йот, как это и произошло в современном чуять: чу+ать.

Comment: Мне вторая версия тоже показалась слишком смелой, поэтому я ее сначала не озвучила. Но раз уж вы попросили :-)...
И насчет этимологических словарей. Они все у меня в электронном виде. Чтобы не зависеть от Сети :-)) Это, конечно, Фасмер. Это Этимологический словарь русского языка Г.П.Цыганенко. Это Историко-этимологический словарь русского языка П.Я.Черных (в 2 томах). Есть еще несколько книг, но основные - эти три.